# Datagrid row hiding, in wpf vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, row

The problem is that i need to hide some rows of the DataGrid, based on which monitor they are displayed.

Here is my code:

```
For Each row As DataRowView In DataGrid1.Items
        cellValue = row.Item("Monitor")
        If cellValue.StartsWith("B") Then
                //the code i need   
        End If
Next
```

The `DataGrid1.Items.Remove()` or `DataGrid1.Items.RemoveAt()` can't be used, cause my ItemSource is in use when they are called.

I prefer changing its visibility to hidden or height to 0.

Sorry if this question is not in the right format or looks bad, this is my first one :P (any tips are welcome)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my code to:

```
Dim numOfRows As Integer
Dim listA As New List(Of Integer)
Dim listB As New List(Of Integer)
Dim deleted As Integer = 0



For Each row As DataRowView In DataGrid1.Items
        numOfRows += 1       'Adding up to total number of rows'
        If row.Item("Monitor").ToString.StartsWith("A") Then
            listA.Add(numOfRows - 1)  'Adding rows indexes to a list'
        ElseIf row.Item("Monitor").ToString.StartsWith("B") Then
            listB.Add(numOfRows - 1)  'Adding rows indexes to a list'
        End If
Next
```

The reason i didn't use `row.Delete()` is because the For Each loop breaks if i change its item source on the run. Thus, I'm deleting the rows on another loop (one for each monitor):

```
Dim rowA As DataRowView
    For Each litem As Integer In listA
        litem -= deleted 

        'The indexes on the list were added in a sorted order'
        'ex. {4,7,14,28,39} . So if i delete the fourth row'
        'all of the rows that remain will have their index'
        'decreased by one,so by using an integer that represents'
        'the number of the deleted rows, i can always delete the'
        'correct "next" row'

        rowA = DataGrid1.Items.Item(litem)
        rowA.Delete()


        deleted += 1
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
row.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
```

P.S.:
In my scope the DataGrid was bound to a `List(Of String)` so i had to get that row first. So when using
`DataGrid.Items(i)` you will only get the item itself which was a `String`.

To get the related `DataGridRow` you have to use this function:

```
DataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(IndexOfItem)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, row.Visibility is not an available option (marked as error) because row is part of DataRowView and not DataGridRow :/


In my case the datagrid is bound directly to a DataSet (DatasetnameViewSource).

Im going to try the ContainerFromIndex method you mentioned ,tomorrow, and ill leave feedback.

Anyway, thanks for your reply :)

Comment: ah yes, i've already added the solution that works for me at april 4:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/15807601/2220089

Comment: Also i couldnt get the containerfromindex work, i dont remember the exact problem i had with it :/ maybe i used it wrong, anyway thanks for your help